# locking the cell value in excell sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have generated an excel using Apache POI, anf the excel sheet is generated succesfully
now the issue is that in my generated excel if somebody forcefully remove the cells
value and add the new value but it should not happen , it should not allow any user
to remove the value from the cell and instead when users try to remove it should immediately pop out,a prompt that sheet is read only, Please advise how to achieve this.
ouput format is HSSF one

Comment: Which output format are you using? .xls (HSSF) or .xlsx (XSSF)

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the entire sheet and make it uneditable.
Please refer to the below list to get the sample code.

[Make column as read-only using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502552/make-column-as-read-only-using-apache-poi)

[Lock single column in Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397169/lock-single-column-in-excel-using-apache-poi)