# How to make a specific section of an excel sheet protected and rest of the cell editable in the whole sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am  using apache poi for populating an excel file,my requirement is to protect the cells i have defined  and the rest of the cells in the excel will be as it is.I am using sheet.protectSheet("") in this operation.But it is making the desired portion locked as well as the rest of the cells in the excel locked also.Is my requirement feasible ?? i am posting my code ,

```
public class ExcelLockStyle {

public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException{

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
    HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)workbook.createSheet("worksheet");
    sheet.protectSheet("password");


    CellStyle lockedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    lockedStyle.setLocked(true); 

    CellStyle defaultStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    defaultStyle.setLocked(false);

   // tried to make the rest of the cell as it is , but not working 
    for(Row row : sheet){
        for(Cell mycell : row){
            mycell.setCellStyle(defaultStyle);
        }
    }
    // Create a header row
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);    
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("locked");
    cell.setCellStyle(lockedStyle);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("this cell unlocked");
    cell.setCellStyle(defaultStyle);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("this column unlocked");
    cell.setCellStyle(defaultStyle);
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

    defaultStyle.setWrapText(true);
    // sets any auto-generated cells in this column to unlocked
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(3, defaultStyle);
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(4, defaultStyle);
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(5, defaultStyle);
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(6, defaultStyle);
    sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(7, defaultStyle);

    FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream("D://doc.xls");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397169/lock-single-column-in-excel-using-apache-poi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @prateek tomar i want to protect the selected region not the whole sheer